# asp.net mvc datetime save to different db table depending on date

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, datetime

I want to save  entries to a database table depending on the DateTime entered. I have a different model and partial view for each month in the year. Users can create events, I want the events to be saved to the corresponding month table in the db so I can return it to the correct view.

So I need some sort of if statement that says 'if the month value of the entered DateTime is x save to tabel x, if y save to y' and so on.

The user will navigate from month to month and pick dates from a html table styled like a calendar, so the entries need to be inserted to the section of the calendar that corresponds to the datetime. This is just to explain why I need this functionality.

If someone can reccomend a more elegant and functional method of achieving this, go right ahead!

I'm sorry I don't have code to post, I have tried a number of ways and failed. I will post code tomorrow morning when I'm at my computer, but this seems quite simple and I'm very new to this lark so if someone could shed light now, that would be great.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't break it out into 12 separate tables.  Store them in a single table.  You could create a computed column that tells you the month number by calculating it from the DateTime value you're already storing.  If your REALLY need to, you can create 12 views off of this table rather easily but I'd take the approach of adding time parameters to your query's WHERE clause.  Make sure you index on the DateTime column.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. So I would have one table with all events, and use a linq query in my controller to decide which view to send events to? I need all months to be browseable, not just the current one. Thanks again, and apologies if I'm a little slow! Still learning..

Comment: I'd recomend not even having the views.  The LINQ query could simply select where date > startOfMonth and date < endOfMonth (psuedocode)

Comment: And for adding events, you only need to add it to the one table.

Comment: But would this only return dates from the current month? I need users to be able to look at events from any moth and events to run past the end of one month and into the start of the next. Could I use seprate controllers with linq queries to return the events from each month from one tabel and add 12 partial views, navigating between them with ajax?

Comment: Well you could design a query to only show the current month entries.  So yes.  Or you could construct the query so that is shows all events that overlap the month they're currently viewing (assuming you store start and end dates).  All you have to do is tweak the where condition to whatever you need on the particular view.

Comment: I have start and end dates. Thanks again, I'll try all this tomorrow and report back, you've definitely brought me further to enlightenment, just takes some linq study I think! Many thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how to add tim parameters in a linq statement?